# Phone number on web page

Tags: html, ios4

Need help on the HTML5 web page. 
When i launch html5 page which has a phone number on that on iphone with iOS 4. It shows it as a link. I dont want it to behave as link.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to remove the telephone link and make it _more difficult_ for an iPhone user to call that phone number on your web page?

Comment: Actually it was a behavior needed. I wanted to show a pop up box when user taps on the link...not the call to directly proceed

Answer (score 4):

[Safari HTML Ref says..](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

By default, Safari on iOS detects any string formatted like a phone number and makes it a 
link that calls the number. Specifying telephone=no disables this feature.
```

Comment: +1 because this works. The crappy way around it if you can't change the header - add it as a link, and then inherit the styles so that it doesn't look like a link. If necessary, attach an 'onclick' handler that returns false (thereby cancelling anything happening when someone clicks the link).

Comment: The meta tag given above doesnot work for me. I want it to be like normal label, where i click on the number aand then user gets a confirmation box to start the call

Comment: Neha - sounds like you want exactly the opposite of what the OP did. Did you try... omitting the meta tag?